Inject ComponentActivity Class with DaggerHilt
I have an implementation class using an Activity Contract to select a ringtone:
 class RingtonePickerImpl @Inject constructor( activity: ComponentActivity )
    : RingtonePicker {
    
        private val ringtonePickerLauncher = activity.registerForActivityResult(
                ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result -> .. 
}

I am using @Inject constructor() to inject the component activity.
I have provided a @Provides function on my di module as follows:
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
object ActivityModule {

    @Provides
    @ActivityScoped
    fun provideComponentActivity(activity: ComponentActivity): ComponentActivity {
        return activity
    }

I also tried this way:
@Provides
    fun provideComponentActivity(@ActivityContext context: Context): ComponentActivity {
        return context as ComponentActivity
    }

However, I am still getting this error:

error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an
@Provides-annotated method.

I have checked that I am using the necessary @Inject constructors on my code.
Are there workarounds for injecting this component safely?

ActivityComponent has binding for Activity and FragmentActivity, but not ComponentActivity. You should inject Activity and convert it to ComponentActivity, for example:
Module:
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
object RingtoneModule {

    @Provides
    @ActivityScoped
    fun provideRingtonePicker(activity: Activity): RingtonePicker =
        RingtonePickerImpl(activity as ComponentActivity)
}

RingtonePickerImpl:
class RingtonePickerImpl(activity: ComponentActivity) : RingtonePicker {



Why do you want to inject ComponentActivity? That doesn't make much sense. The compiler says you need to have @Inject in constructor of ComponentActivity, which you cannot do.

Hi Harry, componentActivity is a dependency for my implementation class and I need it to launch an ActivityResultContract. Is there another way of referencing the componentActivity instead of injecting it on my implementation class.
